# printing elements from an array by alternating first and last

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm learning for loops in JS and am trying to learn how to console.log the first and last element in an array on one iteration, then console.log the second and second to last elements, etc.

here's what I have tried:

```
for (let i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        console.log(myArray[i]);
        console.log(myArray[i-1];
}
```

This is printing elements from my array, but not in the correct order

Comment: maybe you should use while and write i++ before console.log

Comment: The `-` and the `1` were a good direction, but it should have been `console.log(myArray[myArray.length-1-i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you are trying to achieve is to print the last element,  the second last element, etc...

You can use the `myArray.length` property to do it, just substract the **iterator + 1** to the **array length** and obtain the result you want.

```
for (let i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    console.log(myArray[i]);
    console.log(myArray[myArray.length - (i + 1)]);
}
```

The `(i + 1)` is because the `.length` property returns the number of item of the array, but not the maximum index of the array. So if the length of the array is **5**, the maximum index of the array is **4** (since index starts from 0). You can also write it like: `myArray[myArray.length - i - 1]`

Here an example:

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    console.log(myArray[i]);
    console.log(myArray[myArray.length - (i + 1)]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So was my solution not working because by doing console.log(myArray[i-1]), I wasn't actually reaching the end of the array?

Comment: Yes, what you were doing was to print the previous element of the actual index (i - 1). Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary copy of your array, then use [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) (to remove the head element) and [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) (to remove the tail element) until the copy is empty:

```js
const realArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const temporary = realArray.slice();

while (temporary.length) {
  const e1 = temporary.shift();

  // do something with e1
  console.log(e1);

  const e2 = temporary.pop();
  if (e2) {
    // note that e2 _might not exist_ so: always test
    console.log(e2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two counters that works on opposite direction

`i` will move forward with increment as `i++`.

`j` will move backward with decrement as `j--`.

If there are even numbers of elements in an array then you should print both numbers `arr[i]` and `arr[j]`. But be sure to handle the odd number of elemetns in an array then you have to print either of `arr[i]` or `arr[j]`

```js
function print(arr) {
  let i = 0;
  j = arr.length - 1;
  while (i <= j) {
    if (i !== j) {
      console.log(arr[i], arr[j]);
    } else console.log(arr[j]);
    i++;
    j--;
  }
}

print([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
print([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, reverse the array and use the same index. Since `array.reverse()` mutates the original array, we `slice()` it in order to use a copy.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
array.forEach((a, i) => {
  let b = array.slice().reverse()[i]
  if (i < array.length / 2) console.log(a, b)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let output = '';
for (let i = 0; i < (myArr.length) /2; i++){
  output += myArr[i] + myArr[myArr.length-1-i];
}
  console.log(output)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is particularly true when answering old questions (this one is over a year old) with existing answers. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it improves upon what is already here. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Just check for i === 0 to indicate the start of the loop and hence, you can print the last element of array

```js
const myArray = ['first', 1, 2, 3, 'last'];

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++) {
  console.log(myArray[i]);
  if (i === 0) {
    console.log(myArray[myArray.length - 1]);
  }
}
```